# Delayed Job seeking method

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I have a module in a module in Ruby, something akin to:

```
Module Foo
  Module Bar
    def do_thing_as_delayed_job(my_id, my_option_array)
      Delayed::Job.enqueue Foo::Bar.do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
    end
    def do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
      Rails.logger.info("Yay, I got here!")
    end
  end
end
```

I try to fire of the delayed job starter. However, when I run `do_thing_as_delayed_job`, I get this:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `do_thing' for Foo::Bar:Module

I don't know why it's searching in 'Module', how to make it just run the method I want. I'm still fairly new at Ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo::Bar.do_thing` calls `do_thing` on the module itself. You've defined this method as `def do_thing` that makes it an instance method. It means that to call `do_thing` you need to have an instance of that class that has this module mixed in (1) or you need to change this method to a module method (2).

Code for (1)

```
class A
  include Foo::Bar
end

module Foo
  module Bar
    def do_thing_as_delayed_job(my_id, my_option_array)
      Delayed::Job.enqueue A.new.do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
    end
    def do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
      Rails.logger.info("Yay, I got here!")
    end
  end
end
```

Code for (2):

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def do_thing_as_delayed_job(my_id, my_option_array)
      Delayed::Job.enqueue A.new.do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
    end
    def self.do_thing(my_id, my_option_array)
      Rails.logger.info("Yay, I got here!")
    end
  end
end
```

Note that in both cases `module` is lowecase.